# Should I dispose SPWeb or SPList?

Tags: spweb, object-model, dispose

I am doing a whole bunch of things with one SPWeb and many SPLists. If I just dispose web in the `finally` section would that dispose all of SPLists that I instantiated? (btw, I understand the concept of `using`, so should I implement `using` instead?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SPList objects cannot be disposed.

Comment: Thanks Wictor. I guess then run the spweb under the using umbrella should do it. Thanks

Comment: You should not always dispose SPWeb, it depends on the context of where you run the code. If you get your web's from SPContext you must not dispose these webs. As a rule of thumb, webs you create ourself, eg with sitecol.OpenWeb(), you should dispose.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend installing and running this tool to check whether you are disposing your objects correctly: [SPDisposeCheck](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SPDisposeCheck)

Comment: SPDisposeCheck is a good start, but be aware of false positives.

Comment: Note that you can also tag up your project to ignore some of those false positives, when you've considered them and decided that that's what they are. See  http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2011/01/31/sp-2010-developing-for-performance-part-5-disposal-patterns-and-tools.aspx

Answer (score 5):

The rule is complicated, but in a nutshell, you should dispose of any object that you create yourself that implements the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface.

In the context of SharePoint, this includes:

- Any [SPSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.aspx) object you create using `siteColl.OpenWeb()`, returned by `SPSiteCollection.Add`, by the `SPSiteCollection[]` index operator, or yielded in a `SPSiteCollection` `foreach` loop
- Any [SPWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.aspx) object returned from `SPSite.AllWebs.Add`, `SPWebCollection.Add`, the `SPSite.AllWebs[]` index operator or yielded in an `SPSite.AllWebs` foreach loop.

There are many more cases outlined in the [Best Practices: Using Disposable Windows SharePoint Service Objects article on TechNet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248%28v=office.12%29.aspx#Y2622).

Note that [SPList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.aspx) is not in this list (because it does not implement `IDisposable`, nor is [SPList.RootWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.rootweb.aspx) (because you don't create the RootWeb object, you just get a reference to it).

Note that your code is unlikely to compile if you try to `Dispose` an object like `SPList` that doesn't implement `IDisposable`, because that object will not have a `Dispose` method.  On the other hand, you won't get an error if you try to dispose `RootWeb`, because it is an `SPWeb` object with a `Dispose` method - but doing this will cause problems if you try to refer to that web or any of it's children later in your code.

The `using` statement is a bit of syntactic sugar, but I prefer to use it because it ensures that the object is always disposed correctly, and it doesn't require explicit code to ensure that this happens.